# Obj.toString() both equal to false and true?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, tostring

In a blank page on chrome console I type:

```
var o={};
o.toString() == false // false
o.toString() == true // false
```

I'm expecting o.toString to be evaluated as an empty string and so falsy...

What is happening?

Comment: `console.log(o.toString());`

Comment: They are both **NOT** equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm expecting o.toString to be evaluated as an empty string and so falsy...

That expectation is at odds with the [specified behavior of `Object.prototype.toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring) (which is what `({}).toString` is), which is to output `"[object Object]"` for plain objects.

So what you're doing is

```
"[object Object]" == true
```

(or `== false`). If we follow the (convoluted) rules of [the abstract equality comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison), that ends up being

```
Number("[object Object]") === Number(true)
```

...which is

```
NaN === 1
```

...which is `false`, because `NaN` isn't equal to anything.

Similarly

```
"[object Object]" == false
```

...ends up being

```
NaN === 0
```

...which is also `false`, because (again) `NaN` isn't equal to anything.

In a comment you've asked:

> So why not truthy?

There's a big difference between coercing a value to boolean, like this:

```
if (o.toString()) {
```

...and *comparing* it to a boolean via `==`, like this:

```
if (o.toString() == true) {
```

They're just defined fundamentally differently, because `==` goes through a defined series of steps to try to make the values things it can compare, and it doesn't bias toward booleans when doing that (it biases toward numbers and strings).

Comment: nice explenation, thumb up

Comment: I thougth {}.toString was an empty string because an empty array (which is an object too...) give an empty string [].toString() === ""

Comment: @Francesco: `Array.prototype.toString` has very different behavior from `Object.prototype.toString`. The `Array` version converts all of its entries to strings and then does a `.join(",")` on them. So an empty array gives `""`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `{}.tostring()` produces `"[object Object]"`

Your empty string assumption was incorrect and easily tested in a console

Comment: So why not truthy?

Comment: would be truthy if you did `if({}.tostring())`

Comment: @Francesco: There's a big difference between coercing a value to a boolean (`if (o.toString())`) and *comparing* it to a boolean via `==` (`if (o.toSring() == true)`.

Comment: @Francesco could check empty object using `Object.keys(o).length`

Answer (score 0):

It's because `o={}` and  function `toString` return you `"[object Object]"`

If you need to get `true` / `false` if object is empty use something like:

**ES5**

```
var o1 = {};
if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).length !== 0) console.log('true');
else console.log('false');
```

**JQUERY:**
    Check this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

```
if($.isEmptyObject(o)) console.log('true');
```

**Loadash**:

```
if(_.isEmpty(o)) console.log('true');
```

Comment: `if({})` is always truthy